# What is the Error? time data does not match format '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file = os.path.abspath('c:\\Zerodha\\Pi\\Exported\\BAJFINANCE-EQ.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p')
df['Time'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M'))
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%y-%m-%d'))
df.set_index('Date', drop= True, inplace= True)
df.columns = ['O', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'V', 'Time']
df.to_csv('BAJFINANCE-EQ.csv')
```

What should i do? It always says the same Error written Below after changing the format several time as well.

`ValueError: time data '7/22/2020 18:45' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p' (match)`

Comment: I don't see seconds or AM/PM in that timestamp, why does your format suggest it should

Comment: 18:45 would be %I:%M (no %S). Also, there is no AM or PM in the time data.

Comment: Even if i remove the %S and %p flag it gives the same error

Comment: Does it say `ValueError: time data '7/22/2020 18:45' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %I:%M' (match)`?

Comment: @KrishnanShankar Bro it still gives the same error

Comment: @KrishnanShankar yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

try using this format: `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'`, or add seconds and the am/pm to your time text.

Comment: I cant add am/pm or change the data...it will spoil it and even after changing the code it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the format is incorrect. The right format is as follows:
`%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'`

Comment: Nice. If you have the same problem again in the future, you can use this site  to find the correct datetime format: https://strftime.org/.